# unable to retrieve url parameters on Server side using REST API Controller

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

i want to call REST API Controller from my REST API Controller.

**"http://localhost:8080/function/1?filter={"id":1435263}"**

Since we cannot send directly ({"id":1435263})JSON query String along with url because of spring mvc cannot read "{",i am sending query string(Search variables) in the form of map .

```
Object response = restTemplate.getForObject(crudControllerURL,
            Object.class, map);
```

where map contains the values .

On Server side i am **unable to retrieve this map**. I tried @RequestParam Object obj  but it did not work . I am clueless how can i get these values there?

Do i need to convert it into POST?

**EDIT**

when i try to use whole url with query String then i recieve

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not enough variable values available to expand '"id"'
```

Adding Server side contoller code snippet(not whole) and please note i need to access map in Server REST API Controller .
Server side controller

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/{function}/{type}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public List<Order> performFetchAll(@PathVariable String function,
        HttpServletRequest request) throws JsonParseException,
        JsonMappingException, IOException, InvalidAttributesException {
    String requestQueryString = request.getQueryString();
    if (requestQueryString == null
            || requestQueryString.equalsIgnoreCase(""))
        return orderService.findAll();
```

Please provide your feedback. Thanks.

Comment: And how do you think this helps in solving your issue? You post the client code but omit the server side code, which is where the issue is. Also why send son as an argument instead of the body?

Comment: what is the exception coming? Have you configured the message converters??

Comment: i am doing that right away.

Comment: @bilbo baggins no i have not configured any converters

Comment: @M.Deinum ... this is search function. user should able to search using query string and my design demands it to go through url only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should do this probably than complicating the request:

URL can be changed like this : **http://localhost:8080/function/1?idFilter=1435263**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{function}/{type}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public List<Order> performFetchAll(@PathVariable String function, @RequestParam("idFilter") String id, HttpServletRequest request) throws JsonParseException,
        JsonMappingException, IOException, InvalidAttributesException {
//DO something
}
```

If your filter request is going to be big and complex like a json, change your method to POST and take the JSON and do your logic.

Comment: but that filter contains search parameters and that can be anything random entered by User.

Comment: Usually in a typical web application, all the filters would be as part of URL as request parameters. Unless you have a big data to filter, if you have just 2-5 fields of filtration, request parameter would suffice. But as I also mentioned, if data is big, use POST method and use jackson to unmarshal the input.

Comment: ..ok that puts me to right direction i think. thanks